# Tie breaker in function "match"

Tags: r, match

I have a list as follows:

```
rn<-c(10,20,20,10,50,80,100)
rn
#[1]  10  20  20  10  50  80 100
```

I have another list say `q`, which is a sorted version of `rn` in ascending order. I want to find the index of the numbers in `q` in my original list `rn`.

So, I am using `match`:

```
q<-sort(rn)
match(q,rn)
#[1] 1 1 2 2 5 6 7
```

So, `match` behaves as expected and returns the first index for each number being searched for. Thus, even though `10` appears in index `1` and `4` in `rn`, `match` only gets the first one and returns `1` for both searches.

Is there a function in R (or any package), that acts like `match`, but that can handle ties? It should be fine if the tie is broken at random.

Comment: One approach would be to use an all to all (using `outer`) comparison instead of `match` if this does not slow processing down significantly -- `max.col(outer(q, rn, "=="), "random")`, where `max.col` handles ties conveniently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `q` is `rn` sorted in ascending order, you might be able to use `order`

```
order(rn)
#[1] 1 4 2 3 5 6 7
```

In other cases, you could convert the vectors to character and use `make.unique` to account for repeated values

```
match(make.unique(as.character(q)), make.unique(as.character(rn)))
#[1] 1 4 2 3 5 6 7
```

Comment: Sort is doing what I need. Thanks!